# DNS Solver not working correctly

Tags: 64-bit, 15.04, dns

I Just installed 15.04 (64bit) on this machine.
Every time that I tried to connect to a server for the first time, and by this I mean:

- Go to a website
- Updating ubuntu
- Downloading a file
- Anything that involves a hostname

It will always fail the first time, and then work the second one. Although I still can download stuff, is annoying doing everything twice because on the first try it wont load.

I tried adding the Google public DNS servers, and I'm still getting the same problems.

Content of `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

Also, I added the servers through the Network Manager

Comment: in what file did you add google dns? Can you post the whole file

Comment: I added the DNS through the network manager, and in the `/etc/network/interfaces` file.

Comment: You could try adding `nameserver 8.8.4.4` & `nameserver 8.8.8.8.` in `/etc/resolv.conf` - what errors do you get when it tries to resolve DNS (e.g. using your browser ot `ping`, `curl`, `wget` etc)

Answer (score 1):

If that is the entire contents of the file you have some misconfigurations

1)Are you trying to do a DHCP or a staic ip?
2)you misspelled interfaces, see if that is a forum typo or a system typo
3) try this for a static ip

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address 10.10.10.23
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        network 10.10.10.0
        broadcast 10.10.10.255
        gateway 10.10.10.1
        dns-nameservers 10.10.10.2 8.8.8.8
```

Your dns server goes under the interface, likely eth0, but maybe wifi0, try `ifconfig` to see for sure.

For dhcp you still need a line for the interface getting the dhcp config assuming you are using ethernet cord eth0

`auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp`

Comment: The IP is assigned through DHCP

Comment: see edits above